# What is a generator of a finite cyclic group? (General)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I have asked a few questions about this but I am still confused. So, in general, what is a generator of a finite cyclic group and how is it found?
I have seen in books and my notes a lot of descriptions using the term all elements of $G$ are given by $g^n$, for some integer $n$, and where $G = \langle g\rangle$.  But I don't see how this can be the case for many of the groups I'm looking at.

Comment: That is meant To say G=<g>

Comment: Could you give some examples of the groups you are looking at?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft for example U(Z54) = {1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53} but there is no one element that multiplies into all other elements?

Comment: Sure there is, it just takes some tries to find it.

Comment: But most of these elements are prime? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Have you actually tried computing powers of some of those elements?

Comment: I have done yes but it's impossible to reach a prime number using multiplication is it not? Maybe I have the wrong idea for what a generator is?

Comment: Which elements did you compute the powers for, and how high powers?

Comment: I used the element 5 which goes to 25 and then to 125 but it can't,for example, reach the element 11 or 17 using powers. This is why I'm confused

Comment: Remember that you need to reduce $125$ mod $54$.

Comment: So would that be 125-108 giving 17? And do I then keep doing this until all 18 elements are reached?

Comment: Yes (assuming $5$ is a generator which I did not check). There are $6$ generators among the $18$ elements of the group.

Comment: Is this the fastest way to find the generators?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I know very little about the computational aspects of this.

Comment: Okay, thanks. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An element $g\in G$ *generates* the group $G$ if $\{g^k\>|\>k\in{\mathbb Z}\}=G$. A group containing such a $g$ is called *cyclic*. Such a group is automatically abelian, so that we may write the group operation additively.

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $n\geq1$. If $g$ is a generator of $G$ then $G=\{ k\,g\>|\, 0\leq k<n\}$, and $n\, g=0$. This $g$ is not uniquely determined: Let $r$ be any number relatively prime to $n$. Then $h:=r\, g$ is again a generator of $G$. Conversely: Any generator of $G$ can be obtained from $g$ in this way.

The proof of these facts involves no group theory per se, but the elements of divisibility theory of integers.